# Custom control does not exist in the namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I've been interested in WPF bindings in c# and tried to bind a control to the mouse position, but after getting a frustrating "The name "[control]" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:[namespace]" every time I pasted the xaml code into the editor I decided it wasn't worth the time to investigate the quirk.

Now I am attempting to simply implement a [binded Arc drawing example from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667072/how-to-draw-arc-with-radius-and-start-and-stop-angle) and am getting the same eror again. **(All the code for a short runnable example can be found there)**

So I've combed through all the Stack Overflow solution to this issue (it actually seems rather widespread) with what appear to be **sporadic** and **inexpiable** workarounds and fixes.

---

1. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189127/the-name-xxx-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-yyy-xaml-vs12-windows-8) says that

> If nothing else is possible, comment the lines which use the namespace, rebuild, and then build the full project again.
>
> I also tried rebuilding the project, reopening Visual Studio. Nothing
>   helped. I finally commented xaml, rebuilt the project, uncommented
>   xaml and it finally worked! Strange issue.

2. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665713/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-error-in-xaml) said to set the project to release mode and another answer-er on the same question said to define the assembly: (`xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MusicPlayer.Controls;assembly=MusicPlayer"`) which did not work for me either.
3. [This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216096/wpf-the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace) recommended changing the build target platform (x86 - x64)

---

I've tried pretty much all of these solution to no avail. ReSharper seems to know that Arc class exists in the namespace assigned to Local, but Visual Studio does not.

```
<Local:Arc Center="{Binding Path=PreviousMousePositionPixels}" 
         Stroke="White" 
         StrokeDashArray="4 4"
         SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
         StartAngle="0" 
         EndAngle="{Binding Path=DeltaAngle}" 
         SmallAngle="True"
         Radius="40"/>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

public sealed class Arc : Shape
{
    public Point Center
    {
        get { return (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CenterProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Center.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Center", typeof(Point), typeof(Arc)
        , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(0, 0), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));


    public double StartAngle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(StartAngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StartAngleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StartAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StartAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc)
        , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double EndAngle
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(EndAngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EndAngleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EndAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EndAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc)
        , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Math.PI/2.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    public double Radius
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Radius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(Arc)
        , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));



    public bool SmallAngle
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(SmallAngleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SmallAngleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SmallAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallAngleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SmallAngle", typeof(bool), typeof(Arc)
        , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));


    static Arc()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Arc), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Arc)));
    }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {

            var a0 = StartAngle < 0 ? StartAngle + 2 * Math.PI : StartAngle;
            var a1 = EndAngle < 0 ? EndAngle + 2 * Math.PI : EndAngle;

            if (a1<a0)
            {
                a1 += Math.PI * 2;
            }

            SweepDirection d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
            bool large;

            if (SmallAngle)
            {
                large = false;
                double t = a1;
                if ((a1-a0)>Math.PI)
                {
                    d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
                }
                else
                {
                    d = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
                }


            }else{
                large = (Math.Abs(a1 - a0) < Math.PI);
            }

            Point p0 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a0), Math.Sin(a0)) * Radius;
            Point p1 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a1), Math.Sin(a1)) * Radius;


            List<PathSegment> segments = new List<PathSegment>(1);
            segments.Add(new ArcSegment(p1, new Size(Radius, Radius), 0.0, large, d, true));

            List<PathFigure> figures = new List<PathFigure>(1);
            PathFigure pf = new PathFigure(p0, segments, true);
            pf.IsClosed = false;
            figures.Add(pf);

            Geometry g = new PathGeometry(figures, FillRule.EvenOdd, null);
            return g;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try and to drag and drop the Arc class from the Visual Studio toolbox is comes up with a dialog box "The following reference has been added to project "[Namespace]. Version 1.0.0.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" In order to use types from the new reference, press OK to restart the XAML designer. After the Designer restarts, re-create the control on the artboard" **before doing nothing**

Comment: Arc class code isn't wrapped in a namespace.  Could that be your problem?

Comment: @RobCroll I didn't post the code with my namespace, it is wrapped within a namespace.

Comment: Check to make sure your project does not have conflicting namespaces and names. Although rare, sometimes this happens and it can give this error too.

Answer (score 0):

Define Arc inside a namespace as suggested by RobCroll. Check below code, I have included it in the Arc_Learning namespace which is referred in XAML as local.

```
    <Window x:Class="Arc_Learning.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Arc_Learning"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:Arc
             Stroke="White" 
         StrokeDashArray="4 4"
         SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
         StartAngle="0" 
         EndAngle="{Binding Path=DeltaAngle}" 
         SmallAngle="True"
         Radius="40"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Arc_Learning
{
    public sealed class Arc : Shape
    {
        public Point Center
        {
            get { return (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CenterProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Center.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Center", typeof(Point), typeof(Arc)
            , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(0, 0), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));


        public double StartAngle
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(StartAngleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StartAngleProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StartAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StartAngleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StartAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc)
            , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public double EndAngle
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(EndAngleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(EndAngleProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EndAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty EndAngleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("EndAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc)
            , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Math.PI / 2.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public double Radius
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Radius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(Arc)
            , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));



        public bool SmallAngle
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(SmallAngleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SmallAngleProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SmallAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallAngleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("SmallAngle", typeof(bool), typeof(Arc)
            , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));


        static Arc()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Arc), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Arc)));
        }

        protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
        {
            get
            {

                var a0 = StartAngle < 0 ? StartAngle + 2 * Math.PI : StartAngle;
                var a1 = EndAngle < 0 ? EndAngle + 2 * Math.PI : EndAngle;

                if (a1 < a0)
                {
                    a1 += Math.PI * 2;
                }

                SweepDirection d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
                bool large;

                if (SmallAngle)
                {
                    large = false;
                    double t = a1;
                    if ((a1 - a0) > Math.PI)
                    {
                        d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        d = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
                    }


                }
                else {
                    large = (Math.Abs(a1 - a0) < Math.PI);
                }

                Point p0 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a0), Math.Sin(a0)) * Radius;
                Point p1 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a1), Math.Sin(a1)) * Radius;


                List<PathSegment> segments = new List<PathSegment>(1);
                segments.Add(new ArcSegment(p1, new Size(Radius, Radius), 0.0, large, d, true));

                List<PathFigure> figures = new List<PathFigure>(1);
                PathFigure pf = new PathFigure(p0, segments, true);
                pf.IsClosed = false;
                figures.Add(pf);

                Geometry g = new PathGeometry(figures, FillRule.EvenOdd, null);
                return g;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same code as you, except my namespace if different. When I hover over local:Arc, I see "The name "Arc" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:CustomControlTest". Where CustomControlTest is my namespace. If I build and run, the Arc doesn't even show up.

Answer (score 0):

try to add local reference to your window as follow:

in the opening tag of your window add this reference

`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlTest"`

in code behind `C#` Code you missing the namespace definition

add the missing namespace line before the class definition so your code should be like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CustomControlTest
{
    public sealed class Arc : Shape
    {
        public Point Center
        {
    get { return (Point)GetValue(CenterProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CenterProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Center.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Center", typeof(Point), typeof(Arc)
    , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Point(0, 0), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));


public double StartAngle
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(StartAngleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(StartAngleProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for StartAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty StartAngleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("StartAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc)
    , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

public double EndAngle
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(EndAngleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(EndAngleProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EndAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty EndAngleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("EndAngle", typeof(double), typeof(Arc)
    , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Math.PI/2.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

public double Radius
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Radius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(Arc)
    , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(10.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));



public bool SmallAngle
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(SmallAngleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SmallAngleProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SmallAngle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty SmallAngleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SmallAngle", typeof(bool), typeof(Arc)
    , new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));


static Arc()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Arc), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Arc)));
}

protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
{
    get
    {

        var a0 = StartAngle < 0 ? StartAngle + 2 * Math.PI : StartAngle;
        var a1 = EndAngle < 0 ? EndAngle + 2 * Math.PI : EndAngle;

        if (a1<a0)
        {
            a1 += Math.PI * 2;
        }

        SweepDirection d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
        bool large;

        if (SmallAngle)
        {
            large = false;
            double t = a1;
            if ((a1-a0)>Math.PI)
            {
                d = SweepDirection.Counterclockwise;
            }
            else
            {
                d = SweepDirection.Clockwise;
            }


        }else{
            large = (Math.Abs(a1 - a0) < Math.PI);
        }

        Point p0 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a0), Math.Sin(a0)) * Radius;
        Point p1 = Center + new Vector(Math.Cos(a1), Math.Sin(a1)) * Radius;


        List<PathSegment> segments = new List<PathSegment>(1);
        segments.Add(new ArcSegment(p1, new Size(Radius, Radius), 0.0, large, d, true));

        List<PathFigure> figures = new List<PathFigure>(1);
        PathFigure pf = new PathFigure(p0, segments, true);
        pf.IsClosed = false;
        figures.Add(pf);

        Geometry g = new PathGeometry(figures, FillRule.EvenOdd, null);
        return g;
    }
}
}
}
```

add this `namespace CustomControlTest` and then it contains the class

Comment: I have the namespace declared, I didn't include it in the code I posted above.

Comment: then add this to your window tag:  

`<window  

 .....  

 .....  

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlTest"  

 ......  

  ......>`  
@KiroYakuza

Comment: Can you please post your `<window>` opening tag
and also your code behind `C#` code from first using to the class definition 
and make sure you added the reference `System.Drawing`